# Table of Top Five with Pertinent Information in Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, count, format

I have a large csv file that I want to convert into a table with the pertinent information. I would select the top five callers, then include some data underneath such as the last call description, and the person who received the most calls from that customer.

It is something like this:

```
ComplaintNumber;CompanyName;CallerName;EmpName;CallStatus;Gen_Code;Detail Code;OtherDetail;CallDesc;QualityIssue;HighPriority;Received Data and Time; Call Type;count;Unnamed: 14;Unnamed: 15;Unnamed: 16;Unnamed: 17;Unnamed: 18;Unnamed: 19;Unnamed: 20;Unnamed: 21;Unnamed: 22;Unnamed: 23   
5651;Company 1;joe;Rob;Closed;Maintenance;Code 1;;Sentence that is relatively long but not too long;No;1-No;6/11/2015 15:00;Type 1;8;;;;;;;;;;  
6642;Company 1;joe;Rob;Closed;Support;Code 2;;another sentence that is relatively long but not too long;No;1-No;6/12/2015 15:00;Type 2;8;;;;;;;;;;  
6893;Company 1;joe;Rob;Closed;Support;Code 2;;description and stuff;No;1-No;6/13/2015 15:00;Type 3;8;;;;;;;;;;  
4535;Company 1;joe;Gwen;Closed;Maintenance;Code 4;;So and so called and said such and such;No;1-No;6/14/2015 15:00;Type 2;8;;;;;;;;;;   
8655;Company 1;joe;Gwen;Closed;Support;Code 56;;Somebody needs a nap     apparently;No;1-No;6/15/2015 15:00;Type 1;8;;;;;;;;;;
8656;Company 1;joe;Wendy;Closed;Computer;Code 12;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/12/2015 15:00;Type 1;8;;;;;;;;;;
8857;Company 1;joe;Sarah;Closed;Computer;Code 3;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/17/2015 15:00;Type 4;8;;;;;;;;;;
3348;Company 1;joe;John;Closed;Computer;Code;Red;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/18/2015 15:00;Type 4;8;;;;;;;;;;
6679;Company 2;Belinda;John;Closed;Maintenance;Code 4;;Yup   just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/4/2015 19:00;Type 4;7;;;;;;;;;;
5510;Company 2;Belinda;Bob;Closed;Support;Code 1;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;;6/20/2015 15:00;Type 4;7;;;;;;;;;;
7711;Company 2;Belinda;Bob;Closed;Support;Code 1;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/21/2015 12:00;Type 4;7;;;;;;;;;;
6212;Company 2;Belinda;Bob;Closed;Support;Code 4;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/22/2015 15:00;Type 2;7;;;;;;;;;;
4413;Company 2;Belinda;Bob;Closed;Support;Code 34;;Yup   just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/23/2015 5:00;Type 2;7;;;;;;;;;;
1444;Company 2;Belinda;Bob;Closed;Support;Code 2;Blue;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/23/2015 15:00;Type 2;7;;;;;;;;;;
5515;Company 2;Rodger;Yolanda;Closed;Maintenance;Code 1;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/25/2015 15:00;Type 2;7;;;;;;;;;;
1756;Company 3;Janet;Yolanda;Closed;Maintenance;Code 2;;Yup  just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/26/2015 15:00;Type 2;5;;;;;;;;;;
1557;Company 3;Janet;Yolanda;Closed;Computer;Code 4 ;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/27/2015 15:00;Type 2;5;;;;;;;;;;
1238;Company 3;Janet;Yolanda;Closed;Computer;Code 45;Purple;Yup  just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/28/2015 15:00;Type 1;5;;;;;;;;;;
1729;Company 3;Richard;Steve;Closed;Computer;Code 2 ;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/29/2015 15:00;Type 1;5;;;;;;;;;;
2340;Company 3;Richard;Fred;Closed;Support;Code 4;Yellow;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;6/30/2015 15:00;Type 3;5;;;;;;;;;;
2131;Company 4;Pamela;Rob;Closed;Maintenance;Code 5;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/1/2015 15:00;Type 3;3;;;;;;;;;;
2662;Company 4;Pamela;Rob;Closed;Maintenance;Code 6;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/2/2015 15:00;Type 3;3;;;;;;;;;;
2833;Company 4;Pamela;Rob;Closed;Maintenance;Code 7;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/3/2015 15:00;Type 3;3;;;;;;;;;;
2564;Company 5;Stan;Steve;Closed;Computer;Code 8;;Yup    just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/4/2015 15:00;Type 3;1;;;;;;;;;;
2225;Company 6;Lee;Steve;Closed;Computer;Code 9;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/5/2015 15:00;Type 4;1;;;;;;;;;;
1326;Company 7;Jackie;Steven;Closed;Support;Code 10;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/6/2015 15:00;Type 1;1;;;;;;;;;;
7227;Company 8;Jake;Rob;Closed;Support;Code 11;;Yup  just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/7/2015 15:00;Type 2;1;;;;;;;;;;
4228;Company 9 ;Steve;Wendy;Closed;Computer;Code 12;;Yup     just typing random notes here;No;1-No;7/8/2015 15:00;Type 3;1;;;;;;;;;;
```

I want to make a table that has the top five callers as headings and underneath the EmpName (whoever took the most calls from that customer), the Gen_code, and a sentence from the most recent (the calls also have a date and time received column) CallDesc.

Output will be laid out like this table (obviously with different inputs)

[image]

I would appreciate even just guidance on how to approach this problem. Pseudocode is fine. Even better if there's a quick, easy way!

So far I've sorted my list so that the customers that show up with the most frequency are at the top of the list. But from there I don't know how to get the most recent call description or even how to just select the top five.

Answer (score 0):

Read the table into a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
filename = 'my_file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')
```

Create a pivot table: employer names vs caller names.

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index='CallerName', columns='EmpName', values='ComplaintNumber', aggfunc='count')
# clean the table from NaNs (not necessary, but more beautiful):
pivot.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Create a new column sum and save the sum of each caller into it:

```
pivot['sum'] = pivot.sum(axis=1)
```

Sort the table using the sum column descending:

```
pivot.sort('sum', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Print the first 5 results of this table

```
print(pivot[:5])
```

I hope this is what you wanted!

EDIT: You can now groupby the original dataframe by Callers and only select the top 5 ones and display all the information desired.

EDIT2:A "pivot[:5].transpose()" will bring you very close to the final table form you suggested, where the top five callers are the table "headers"

Comment: This is close to what I want, but not quite! This gives a nice table with the top callers and columns with the Emp Names and how many calls each employee got... but I'm looking for it to select the one employee that picked up the most calls for the caller, and underneath that, the Gen_Code that occurred most for that customer.